# C++ Initialization by making a copy or using reference depending on the condition

Tags: c++, reference, copy-constructor

І have a `bool` variable named `do_copy`.

If `do_copy == true`, I want to work with a copy, like
`some_type model = input_model`

If `do_copy == false`, I want to work with a reference, like
`some_type& model = input_model`

Code that does what I want:

```cpp
some_type copy_model;
if (do_copy)
    copy_model = input_model;
some_type& model = do_copy ? copy_model : input_model;
```

It does not look very good, and I call the default constructor, which isn't necessary for `do_copy == false`.

Is there a way to make it more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might make the copy as part of the ternary expression:

```
some_type copy_model;
some_type& model =
    do_copy
    ? (copy_model = input_model, copy_model)
    : (input_model);
```

This still requires default constructing `copy_model` even when `do_copy` is false. If your default constructor is really expensive, you might use an optional:

```
std::optional<some_type> copy_model;
some_type& model =
    do_copy
    ? (copy_model = input_model, *copy_model)
    : (input_model);
```

Note that this doesn't come completely for free: the destructor of `std::optional<some_type>` has an extra branch as compared to `some_type`.

And if you find yourself needing to do this very often, why not wrap this pattern in a class:

```
template<class T>
struct copy_or_reference
{
    std::optional<T> maybeCopy;
    T& ref;

    copy_or_reference(copy_tag, T& x)
        : ref(x)
    {};

    copy_or_reference(reference_tag, const T& x)
        : maybeCopy(x), ref(*maybeCopy)
    {};

    operator T& () const { return ref; };
    operator T& () { return ref; };
};

template<class T>
auto make_copy_or_reference(bool copy, T& x)
{
    return copy ? copy_or_reference<T>(copy_tag{}, x) : copy_or_reference<T>(reference_tag{}, x);
}


void do_something(some_type&);

void do_something_else()
{
    ...
    copy_or_reference<some_type> model = make_copy_or_reference(do_copy, input_model);
    do_something(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to avoid the unnecessary constructor is to only allocate `copy_model` dynamically if it's needed:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<some_type> copy_model;
if (do_copy)
    copy_model = std::make_unique<some_type>(input_model);
some_type& model = copy_model ? *copy_model : input_model;
```

I'm not sure that's much more elegant though.

Comment: @cigien that wasn't a typo but thanks for being thorough :)

Comment: Oh, I see. You were using the conversion to bool to check the same thing. My bad, please do rollback to the version you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Move the logic that uses `model` into a separate function:

```cpp
void doSomething(some_type& model)
{
    //...
}

...

if (do_copy)
{
    some_type copy_model = input_model;
    doSomething(copy_model);
}
else
    doSomething(input_model);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/dqyj6e)

Alternatively, in C++11 and later:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T&& model) // T will be lvalue-ref or rvalue-ref depending on input
{
    //...
}

...

if (do_copy)
    doSomething(some_type{input_model});
else
    doSomething(input_model);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/RAiirS)